# Synchronize read and write access for an image

Tags: c#, .net, image, web-applications, synchronization

We have a single image on the server that's regularly amended from the code. It's a kind of tiled mosaic, so new tiles reveal as users upload photos.

And it should be accessible anytime to the website users for viewing.

The problem is synchronization. When reading and writing occurs simultaneously, sometimes the image doesn't get loaded on the website properly.

What is the correct approach to synchronize reading and writing for the image in this scenario?

Comment: A semaphore maybe? How big is the picture and how long does it take to write? Even a 5MB image should only take a few milliseconds to write and that will be as nothing compared to the time to transmit the image over the web to the client so in percentage terms it should be imperceptible. I mean a modern disk does 100-150MB/s, and few of us have an Internet link over 80Mbits/s (10MB/s) so the disk is 10x faster and write delays should be masked by Internet transfer times. Or is your setup different?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to have two images, The first one is for reading and the second one is for modifications.

The modifications are performed on the second image and are synchronized so that one user modifies it at a time (You can queue modifications if you do not want to lock user call).

After modification is performed you can commit the changes to the first image and users can then get the modifications.

In this approach users may get the modifications a little bit late (depending on the commit time)

Comment: What if the first image is requested while it's still being written to the file?

Comment: The commit procedure doesn't take any time (Copy of the second image and delete the first one) so it might be safe to lock the resource until it is modified